# docusaurus fix color scheme for a specific page

Tags: themes, darkmode, docusaurus

I'd like to display a certain page in docusaurus always in dark-mode without the user being able to change it, (but still have the rest of the pages as usual where the mode can be selected by the user).

Any ideas on how this can be achieved? e.g., the navbar setting has a property `style` where it can be set to dark, but this is just for the navbar globally and I'm wondering if something like this exists for individual pages.